# Shape classification by color - computer vision

Tags: classification, computer-vision

I have task of classification of polygons. These shapes may differ only by color, or be transformed by linear transformation (scaled, rotated). I am using ORB for separating different polygons, but it cannot take colors into account.

What computer vision algorithm can help me solve this problem?[image]

Comment: If you can separate the shape, you can just compare the pixels of two shapes to check if they are the same or not? Just compute the norm of difference between the images, if it's low (close to zero), the colors are the same. You may blur the images a bit at first (by Gaussian bluring) to get more robust results.

Comment: I stated my problem incorrectly. My classes may be rotated, scaled etc, but some classes are only colored differently, so ORB cannot separate them.

Comment: What about using a simple CNN for this task?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple technique can be used is firstly apply **thresholding** on image and then finding **contours** to detect shapes.

Comment: Welcome to CV. This answer as it currently stands is closer to a comment than to an answer. To avoid having it deleted, could you please provide more details, explanations, links to resources, references etc.? Thanks!